# System.getProperty("user.dir") giving path of eclipse while executing through web service

Tags: java, web-services

While executing System.getProperty("user.dir") from a simple java class, it gives me correct path like workspace/projectName. But when I write the same code in service method of a REST web service and execute it through its client app on chrome, it gives me the path where eclipse is located and not the current directory. Is there any way to get path of current working directory or the path where java file(service) is located. I need this because I want to read a property file which is placed in same path as the java file.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` should work

Comment: Which server are you using? Tomcat?

Comment: @Hasslarn yes i am using tomcat

Comment: Clarify your thinking. It isn't 'executing through web service' at all. It is executing *the web service* through Eclipse. A properly written web-app doesn't need to know its absolute path at all, and if it does there are plenty of mechanism that will provide it.

Comment: 'It gives me the path where eclipse is located and not the current directory' Wrong. It *does* give you the current directory, which in this case *is* the path where Eclipse is located. The problem here is in your expectations.

Comment: @EJP I meant the code is being executed through web service. You are correct but I need to know absolute path because I am not able to use relative path. I understand that eclipse is working directory so it is giving me the path of eclipse. But my question is 'Is there any way to get path of current working directory or the path where java file(service) is located'?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and got it resolved using configuration change. Change the location of working directory in Eclipse using Run -> Run Configurations. On Arguments Tab select Other radio button and specify Workspace or any custom location as a Working directory.

Comment: For me the directory was not proper under apache tomcat server  > arguments > working directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get path of current working directory

Yes.  You are already getting the current directory that is in force when you run the application.

> ... it gives me the path where eclipse is located and not the current directory.

Sorry ... but that is the current directory.  Yes ... >>IT IS<<.  If you disagree, then your understanding of what "current directory" means is incorrect.

> ... or the path where java file(service) is located. I need this because I want to read a property file which is placed in same path as the java file.

There is no way to do that portably and reliably.  (Of course, you could put the absolute path of the real property file into a second property file ... but then you've got the problem of finding the second property file ...)

The solutions are:

- Put the properties file inside the JAR file, and access it using `getResourceAsStream(path)`.
- Put the properties file in a well-known location; e.g. the user's home directory.  (Actually, the home directory is probably a poor choice for a Service.)