# Not able to access file in eclipse gives : FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse i am trying to give path of one configuration.json file but it is not taking it .

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

gives `C:\Users\cmalik\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse`
and

```
try {
            File f = new File("."); // current directory

            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.print("directory:");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("     file:");
                }
                System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        }
```

gives

```
file:C:\Users\cm\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse\Eclipse Jee Neon.lnk
file:C:\Users\cm\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse\hs_err_pid10180.log
file:C:\Users\cm\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse\hs_err_pid9728.log
```

And my project structure is

```
ProjectName
  ---src
      ---- com.abc.def.ghi.jkl.WebServices
                              ------ myService.java
  ---configuration.json
```

I tried code for accessing file is :

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("configuration.json");
or
FileReader file = new FileReader("projectName\\configuration.json");
```

It is not able to access as output for System.getProperty("user.dir") is eclipse folder not my current projectName folder.
How can i get my files please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the below two:

```
String location=System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

or

```
String location= new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

And then try to access the file using:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader(location+"\\configuration.json");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: String location=System.getProperty("user.dir"); gives C:\Users\cmalik\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse

Comment: What did you mean by the above comment?

Comment: `String location=System.getProperty("user.dir");   `                                           gives                                           `C:\Users\cm\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse\.`

Comment: If its the path returned then answer the below questions: a) Have you ever succed in executing any java code in your eclipse setup. Try executing a simple java app. Because the code is fine I have executed it, problem is with setup.

Comment: You can check the code functionality even by creating a java class in any local folder and try executing it from cmd.

Comment: Yes i am running the whole project in eclipse which is maven project and using jersey..but now requirement arise i need to add 1 configuration and read from that file

Comment: In other project `String location=System.getProperty("user.dir"); ` gives me my current project directory.. but for this application i dont know why eclipse gives me `C:\Users\cm\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse\.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171555/discussion-between-shepherd-and-user3756799).

Comment: I got the solution thank you for your time from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839955/system-getpropertyuser-dir-giving-path-of-eclipse-while-executing-through-we?rq=1

Comment: Can you please accept this answer (Click on the grey tick to accept it) , so that people can refer it. Even the link suggested by you in comments would be a help.